# How to fetch images from response of themoviedb api

Tags: java, android, themoviedb-api

I'm getting the following JSON response from themoviedb API:

```
{
         "popularity":1640.159,
         "vote_count":32,
         "video":false,
         "poster_path":"\/9Rj8l6gElLpRL7Kj17iZhrT5Zuw.jpg",
         "id":734309,
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"\/7fvdg211A2L0mHddvzyArRuRalp.jpg",
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Santana",
         "genre_ids":[
            28
         ],
         "title":"Santana",
         "vote_average":6.3,
         "overview":"Two brothers — one a narcotics agent and the other a general — finally discover the identity of the drug lord who murdered their parents decades ago. They may kill each other before capturing the bad guys.",
         "release_date":"2020-08-28"
      }
```

I have to use `poster_path` but I'm unable to understand it as it's just the image name but not any path. I've no idea how can I get the image from this `poster_path` string.

Please help me! When I paste the url on Google I got nothing.

Comment: "poster_path":"\/9Rj8l6gElLpRL7Kj17iZhrT5Zuw.jpg", could be the image name which needs to be appended after your server path may be. You can clarify this from the recruiter itself.

Comment: @Astha No that didn't happened.

Answer (score 18):

As per the  [the movie db doc](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/images), it's in the following format:-

```
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/your_poster_path
```

(Taking poster path from your question, now you can see image by pasting this in browser as URL - http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/9Rj8l6gElLpRL7Kj17iZhrT5Zuw.jpg )

Either use Glide or picasso to show it by following other answers.

Comment: This really worked well. Thanks @Astha

Comment: @AbhishekUpadhyay Can you mark the answer as accepted if it helped you with your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use glide library to fetch and display image from the server. check below URL. 
-- https://bumptech.github.io/glide/
contains how to use glide.

```
 Glide
        .with(may be context)
        .load(url)
        .into(your Image View);
```